# Design a Suite of products while building/maintaining only one

Tags: architecture

There would be an application that will do 3 major things. `A`, `B` and `C`. It is going to be a C# winforms application.

Our CEO wants this application to be divided into 6 different products.

- Just A (Simple)
- A + B (Advanced)
- A + B + C (Ultimate)

and all this for one user or multiple users (licensing). Thus, we now have 6 projects!

If we suppose that the three major parts are indeed separated and can work on their own, how can we maintain **one** project and be selling 6?

At the moment there are three ways to accomplish this, that come to my mind:

**A:** Have a basic backbone and build each of the A,B,C as a module. This way we only have to deal with the -one/many users- issue.

**B:** Create one solid product and use preprocessor directives to set functionality at compile time. This is really difficult and makes code ugly. Also, might break the project.

**C:** Create a versioning mechanism that will be set to allow certain functionality over the application. This is the easiest to go but has two drawbacks. It is easy to crack and we deliver the Ultimate version for a Simple user, which is bad.

Similar to this is the Windows versioning issue (Home, Basic, Pro, Ultimate)

How should we design this Project?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Modularity** - The decision between A and B method  is difficult. First it is important to differentiate modularity in terms of how the app presents itself to the user in UI and modularity in the app's underlying architecture. (bussiness logic, data layer, etc..) while acknowledging that the second reflects the first. AFAIK WinForms doesn't provide a very strict separation of presentation layer and business layer and you would need to make some additional effort to separate the layers better in order to have flexibility in UI without the need to rewrite much code. This means if you design the business layer to strictly reflect "UI modules"..you will be stuck with it and then it is maybe easier to turn of modules according to the sales. But if you want to preserve flexibility in the future, separate the layers and turn off each and every functionality separately by preprocessor directives.

2) **Endproduct vs. production** - The fact that you would maybe have different endproducts or builds containng A or A+B, 1 user or many users etc..doesn't mean you need to divide the code and the job that way..Visual Studio allows you for sure to create templates for different "release" builds, that would or wouldn't contain this or that module or functionality.